# Riesz representation theorem for $\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, and let $V^*$ denote its dual space, consisting of all continuous linear functionals from $V$ into the field $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. If $x$ is an element of $V$, then the function $φ_x$, for all $y$ in $V$ defined by
$$\varphi_x(y) = \left\langle y , x \right\rangle,   $$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product of the Hilbert space, is an element of $V^*$. The Riesz representation theorem states that every element of $V^*$ can be written uniquely in this form.

Let us consider a linear and continuous operator on a Hilbert space $V$, $\mathcal A:V\rightarrow V$, such that: 
$$\|\mathcal A u\|\leq M \|u\|, \ \ \forall u\in V, M>0$$
and now consider $\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle, \ \ u,v\in V.$
Since:
$$\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle\leq \|\mathcal A u\| \|v\|\leq M \|u\|\|v\|$$
Can we infer $\varphi_x(u)=\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$ continuous and linear?

Comment: Linearity follows from the properties of the inner product (or conjugate linearity, depending on your flavour), and you have shown boundedness which is equivalent to continuity here. The corresponding $x$ is, of course, $A^* v$.

Comment: @copper.hat: thank you very much!

Comment: You did the work :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $u\mapsto \varphi_x(u)=\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle$ is obviously a linear form on V. Given that $\mathcal{A} $ is linear and $\langle\cdot,v\rangle$ is linear too. 
 Moreover, applying the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and the continuity of   $\mathcal{A} $ respectively, we obtain

$$|\varphi_x(u)|=|\langle\mathcal A u,v\rangle|\le  \|\mathcal A u\| \|v\|\le\|\mathcal A \|  \|u\|\|v\| = M \| u\| $$ with $M=\|\mathcal A \|\|v\|  .$ This show the continuity of $\varphi_x.$